# Groovy star import and usage of "partial" packages

Tags: groovy, language-design

To my surprise I have learned today that the following works just fine in Groovy:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*

def atomicBool = new atomic.AtomicBoolean(true)
```

i.e. after the star import, I can use a 'partial' package to refer to `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean`.

Obviously, the same is not valid in Java:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // compiler error: 'atomic' cannot be resolved to a type
        new atomic.AtomicBoolean(true);
    }
}
```

So it seems that Groovy's idea of a package is similar to C++ (or C#) namespaces in this regard.

Question to the Groovy experts:

- Is this by design or is it a (potentially unintended) side effect of the way the interpreter treats star imports?
- If it is by design, can you point me to a section in the documentation or language specification where this behavior is documented? (There is no mention of this in the documentation on [Star Import](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_star_import) and neither in the language spec as far as I can tell or at least I couldn't find anything.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Groovy source code, this behavior seems to be intended. Before we dig deeper into Groovy internals you have to be aware of one thing - Groovy compiles to a bytecode that can be represented by a valid Java code. It means that Groovy code like the one form your example actually compiles to something like this (without compile static and type checked transformations):

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.Script;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class test extends Script {
    public test() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    }

    public test(Binding context) {
        CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
        super(context);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        var1[0].call(InvokerHelper.class, test.class, args);
    }

    public Object run() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        AtomicBoolean atomicBool = (AtomicBoolean)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[1].callConstructor(AtomicBoolean.class, true), AtomicBoolean.class);
        return var1[2].callCurrent(this, atomicBool);
    }
}
```

As you can see this Java class uses full `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean` import and this is actually what Groovy transforms your input source code to.

#### How does it happen?

As you may know Groovy builds Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) from the input source file and it iterates over all nodes (like expressions, variable definitions, method calls etc.) and applies transformations. Groovy uses class called [`ResolverVisitor`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.java) that is designed to resolve types. When Groovy compiles your code it finds [`ConstructorCallExpression`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/expr/ConstructorCallExpression.java#L31):

```
new atomic.AtomicBoolean(true)
```

It sees that the expected type of the object you are trying to create is `atomic.AtomicBoolean`, so `ResolverVisitor` starts resolving the type by calling [`resolveOrFail(type, cce);` at line 1131](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.java#L1131).

It tries several resolving strategies that fail [until it reaches method `resolveFromModule` at line 695](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.java#L695). What happens here is it iterates over all star imports (single `java.util.concurrent.*` in your case), then it concatenates star import with the type name and it checks if qualified name created from this concatenation is a valid type class. Luckily it is in your case:

[image]

When type gets resolved, Groovy replaces initial type with this resolved valid type name in the abstract syntax tree. After this operation your input code looks more like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*

java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean atomicBool = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean(true)
```

This is what compiler gets eventually. Of course fully qualified name gets replaced with the import (this is what Java compiler does with qualified names).

#### Was this "feature" introduced by designed?

I can't tell you that. However we can read from the source code, that this happens on purpose and type resolving like this is implemented with intention.

#### Why it is not documented?

I guess no one actually recommend using imports that way. Groovy is very powerful and you are able to do many things in a many different ways, but it doesn't mean you should do so. Star imports are pretty controversial, because using star imports over explicit imports makes your code more error-prone due to possible class import conflicts. But if you want to know exact answer to this kind of questions you would have to ask Groovy language designers and core developers - they may give you straight answer without any doubts.